# WAL buffer checkpoint/flush time during serialization isolation

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, checkpoint

I have a doubt regarding the flush/checkpoint time of WAL buffers during serialization isolation in Postgres. Is it possible to lose acknowledged writes even if transaction runs in serialization isolation level? What happens if the transaction was committed to WAL buffer and machine crashes after that and there is no recovery possible? Does Postgres always commit serialization isolation transactions to disk?

Comment: The isolation level has nothing to do with how (technically) a transaction is persisted. It's not possible to lose a transaction (hardware failures aside) if the server signaled that it was successfully committed - regardless of the isolation level.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying !

Comment: That is, unless you have set `synchronous_commit` or (horribile dictu!) `fsync` to something else than `on`.